# How to set n_estimators for mmlspark implementation of LightGBM

Tags: apache-spark, lightgbm

I am using the mmlspark version of LightGBMRanker (but the same question seems to apply to LightGBMClassifier, etc) - when instantiating the estimator, there doesn't seem to be a way to set the "n_estimators" parameter that is present in the normal (non-spark) version of LightGBM.

This basically sets the number of trees in the ensemble.. Does anyone know how to do this, or if this is automatically set somehow?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Per `mmlspark`'s tests, in Scala you can use the instance method `.setNumIterations()`.

```scala
def baseModel: LightGBMRanker = {
    new LightGBMRanker()
      .setLabelCol(labelCol)
      .setFeaturesCol(featuresCol)
      .setGroupCol(queryCol)
      .setDefaultListenPort(getAndIncrementPort())
      .setRepartitionByGroupingColumn(false)
      .setNumLeaves(5)
      .setNumIterations(10)
}
```

reference: https://github.com/Azure/mmlspark/blob/36ee274e93e1f7a07fc863061ad726e5ca5b49ee/src/test/scala/com/microsoft/ml/spark/lightgbm/split2/VerifyLightGBMRanker.scala#L62

If you are using `mmlspark` in Python via `pyspark`, you can set `numIterations` in the constructor of the estimator.

```py
from mmlspark.lightgbm import LightGBMRanker

features_col = 'features'
query_col = 'query'
label_col = 'labels'
lgbm_ranker = LightGBMRanker(
  labelCol=label_col,
  featuresCol=features_col,
  groupCol=query_col,
  predictionCol='preds',
  leafPredictionCol='leafPreds',
  featuresShapCol='importances',
  repartitionByGroupingColumn=True,
  numLeaves=32,
  numIterations=200,
  evalAt=[1, 3, 5],
  metric='ndcg'
)
```

reference: https://github.com/Azure/mmlspark/blob/663d9650d3884ece260a457d9b016088380c2cb9/notebooks/samples/LightGBM%20-%20Overview.ipynb

In LightGBM, `n_estimators` and `n_iterations` both mean the same thing, as mentioned at https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Parameters.html#num_iterations.